# Parse JSON without knowing it's schema or domain object type

Tags: java, json

I have a rest service which returns a JSON String. Rest service will process request and return JSON string's schema is unpredictable. What approach can I take to parse this kind of JSON string to a Pojo or Domain object?

e.g : Rest service can return JSON String which represent Address, Bank Account Info, Employee Details etc.
There is nothing common in all these JSON response.

My current approach is to return a header with ResponeType in it. Wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Isn't the response dependent on the request? How can the *same* request sometimes return an Address, and sometimes something else? --- Anyway, is response to entirely dynamic, then you cannot use POJO, since those are statically defined. You'll just have to parse JSON to a generic JSON tree or nested `Map` structure, which is supported by various JSON parser libraries.

Comment: I guess I have a flaw in design. My use case, Rest Service is a NLP service. After process an input, return type can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the json tree and based on the root node key name, decide on using a corresponding class to use for parsing. This is how it will look like with Jackson:

```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(json);  
   if(rootNode.get("type1") != null) {
       //parse with type1
   }
   ....so on
```